# Google Cloud Compute API: Create a vm with a larger disk size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using nodejs client library, and I am stuck in a situation. I need to create disposable VM on demand, which means those instances would be up for a couple of days and then would be deleted. All of this would happen via an API.

The default size of the disk while creating a VM is 10GB, and I need a larger disk than that.

Is it possible to do that, without creating a disk first and then attaching it to my VM? As that would be a hassle since I'd have to make sure that I'd delete the disk too, whenever I'd delete the instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `compute.instances.insert` [API method](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.insert) to create a Compute Engine instance, and set its `disks[].initializeParams.diskSizeGb` parameter specifying the desired disk size. You can find more information regarding this API call [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert).

Comment: To add to Maxim's correct answer, another method is to create an Compute Engine Instance Template and configure the template as desired. Then launch an instance using the template.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. However, I had already tried this but Google's API responds with "missing source url". So, it turns out it requires that a disk needs to be on the user's project. Good thing is that if you a delete an instance, the API deletes the attached disk as well, so I am fine with that.